# add href link in html panel

Tags: href, kibana

I would like to add a href link in my kibana dashboard. To do that, I add a "text" panel, select "html" mode, and edit the content with :

```
<a ng-href=intro.txt>Introduction</a>
```

When I add it and go to my dashboard, the introduction link appears but it has no href link, so clicking on it is possible but it does nothing.

When I inspect the element with chrome inspector, the tag looks like this:

```
<a>Introduction</a>
```

My json dashboard looks like this :

```
"panels": [
        {
          "error": false,
          "span": 12,
          "editable": true,
          "type": "text",
          "loadingEditor": false,
          "mode": "html",
          "content": "<a ng-href=intro.txt>Introduction</a> ",
          "style": {
            "font-size": "20pt"
          },
          "title": "WELCOME"
        }
      ]
```

I hope someone know how to add an href link in kibana text panel.

Answer (score 2):

Ok I found the solution, the href value must be conform to a particular regex, ie starts with https or ftp or mail. This is to prevent any script injection.